# cake php email helper - internal error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to send email with cake php email component:

`var $components = array('Email');`

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'));
$email->to('xxx@gmail.com');
$email->subject('About');
$email->send('My message');
```

And I always get message: Couldnt send email. Internal error occured.
In error log there is "SocketException".

I am using cakephp 2.0.

How should I configure things to get it work? I don't want to use any smtp servers and so on, I just want to send simple email.

I am using WAMP on my PC.

Comment: Can you send email from a simple php script (without any CakePHP being involved)?

Comment: why are you including a component when you are ending up using the lib instead? also - using windows and NOT using smtp is a pretty difficult thing to set up if you don't know what to do. why not just using the the easy way (smtp is only 4 config strings).

Comment: look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669012/cakephp-2-cakeemail-could-not-send-email-error/19875079#19875079

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the line: `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`. This will resolve your Socket problem.

One more thing I want to say is :

You are mixing two thing core library & component both. FYI

EmailComponent is now deprecated. so use core library instead.

for more details check this link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Answer (score 1):

Debug the exception.

I bet that you can't open a connection to your mail server. Looks more like it's an error with your mail server setup or the connection to it than with CakePHp.

For an easy mail server setup for windows I recommend you to use XAMPP, it comes with the preconfigured mail server Pegasus, works just easy and fast for me.

Answer (score 1):

This really does look like it's an error with your mail server setup or the connection to it. However, you are confusing the CakeEmail class for the EmailComponent.

Firstly you're not trying to send a email with the emailComponent, you are using the new CakeMail class (new from 2.x).
Thus, this:

```
var $components = array('Email');
```

and this:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
```

are two different things. The first loads the EmailComponent, but you're not using it at all. The EmailComponent as of 2.x is deprecated. In your example you're using the CakeEmail Class.

Firstly you should insure that the class is actually loaded:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

Then check if you have the configuration file in:

```
App/Config/email.php
```

I suppose you're currently using the default configuration option. This means that the default transport is 'Mail' - the PHP **mail** function. I suppose you're getting a *SocketException*, because it can't connect to a underlying mail transport agent and because it is trying to do so over a System Socket... (Which I do not think exists in Windows, but I could be wrong. I know for sure that there is something like that in the windows API for inter-process cominucation)

Anyway, using the default email configuration is ok. Read the CakePHP Book's Section on the [CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) class.